# Single line reverse proxy with HTTP Basic Auth

Tags: ubuntu, reverse-proxy, http

I am temporarily exposing some HTTP services to the Internet and I would like to password-protect them. Because the exposure is just a few hours, setting up Nginx, Traefik or other heavy-weight solution might not be worth the time.

Running on Ubuntu Linux. I would like to avoid any configuration files and just run the proxy directly from the command line, so I can easily modify and copy-paste the command around.

What would be ideally a single command line reverse proxy, where you just give the upstream localhost port, username and password, to expose an HTTP port to the Internet in the HTTP Basic Authentication realm?

Anything from Ubuntu apt repositories goes. Also I consider any Docker-based solution if there is something I could grab from Docker Hub that offers setting up the proxy parameters directly from the command line, without configuration files.